# How to use stacks of matricies as input for tensorflow?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy, tensorflow2.0

To get used to TensorFlow I try to train a DNN to estimate 3D stresses from given 3D strains and two material parameters (Hooke's law).

As input I have a samples of 3D strains with shape (NumberOfSamples, 3, 3), material parameter1 (NumberOfSamples, 1), material parameter2 (NumberOfSamples, 1) and finally the corresponding calculated 3D stresses (NumberOfSamples, 3, 3).

I thought of creating a CSV with 4 columns: Stress, Strain, matpar1, matpar2; the rows are the number of samples.

My current solution has the problem, that the columns are lists and not numerical arrays:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Number of samples
samples = 10000 

# Generate random strain from 0 - 0.002 (non-symmetric)
eps_non_symmetric = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=0.002, 
    size=(samples, 3, 3))

# Symmetries strain
eps = np.zeros((samples, 3, 3))

for i in range(samples):
    eps[i, :, :] = np.subtract(
        np.add(eps_non_symmetric[i, :, :], eps_non_symmetric[i, :, :].T),
        np.diag(eps_non_symmetric[i, :, :].diagonal()))

# Generate random shear modulus from 1000 - 300000
shear_modulus = np.random.uniform(low=1000, high=300000, size=(samples, 1))

# Generate random 1. Lame constant from 1000 - 400000
lame_constant = np.random.uniform(low=1000, high=400000, size=(samples, 1))

# Generate stress from Hooke's law 
sig = np.zeros((samples, 3, 3))

for j in range(samples):
    sig[j, :, :] = 2 * shear_modulus[j] * eps[j, :, :] 
    + lame_constant[j] * np.eye(3) * np.trace(eps[j])

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Sig': list(sig), 'Eps': list(eps), 'Shear': list(shear_modulus), 
    'Lame': list(lame_constant)}, 
    columns=['Sig', 'Eps', 'Shear', 'Lame'])

data.to_csv('data.csv', index_label=False)
```

Then, I would open it in another code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

import tensorflow as tf


dataset_path = './data.csv'
raw_dataset = pd.read_csv(dataset_path)
dataset = raw_dataset.copy()

train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8, random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)

def build_model():
    build_model_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', 
        input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    ])

    build_model_model.compile(loss='mse',
                              optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                              metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
    return build_model_model

example_batch = train_dataset[:10]
example_result = model.predict(example_batch)
```

The last line (the test) fails, because I have a list of strings, not floats...

I have no Idea how to give the DNN the right format of my tensors (matrices). I need a possibility to save and load my generated data, which consist of tensors and vectors, each of them as several samples, and then parse it to the network. Does anyone has tried something similar?

Summary: 1. How to convert the pandas string entries to floats?
         2. Is there a better way to feed the DNN with matrix/vector     inputs?

Comment: `cvs` is intended for simple 2d  data - columns are individual numbers.  Look at the file.  Show us a sample.

Comment: Here is an example with two samples:

[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=15c-jGrGx-Hb9YOuXekKJ_-TKstiiGIBv)

When opening, it seems that the rows are shifted, but using pandas to open the .csv everything is normal

Comment: Is there a recommended format for such data shapes?

Comment: The cells in that spreadsheet are strings.

Comment: Yes, and I need several numerical arrays sorted in columns, with rows for every sample. How to obtain that?

Is there a possibility with pandas.DataFrame()?

Comment: Do you have to use `pandas`?  Pandas works best with 2d data, where each row/col cell is a  number.  It can be an `object`, but even then it's best if that object is a string, not a list or array.  When you `csv` it, it has to punt, and write `str(an_array)` to the file.  Such as string is difficult, sometimes impossible to turn back into an array.

Comment: No, I don't need Pandas. Which workflow would you suggest?